# Rally Custom App Checkbox filter not working

Tags: javascript, checkbox, rally

I am trying to create an custom app that allows me to search by Iteration(xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox'), then use a checkbox(xtype: 'checkbox') to show only the "Blocked" items, and display this all on a grid.

I am having trouble with the checkbox. I can't get it to push a filter to only display "Blocked" items on the grid. I have done quite a bit of research, and what I have is the sum of that research(probably part of the problem), but alas, still no progress. Everything displays, but the checkbox does not funtion. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Stories By Iteration</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p4/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            //Containers for all items in the app
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'dropdown'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'checkbox'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'grid'
                }
            ],

            launch: function() {
                //Dropdown box for selecting an iteration
                this.down('#dropdown').add({
                    xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
                    margin: '10px 0px 0px 0px',
                    id: 'iterationComboBox',
                    listeners: {
                        ready: this._onLoad,
                        change: this._onChange,
                        scope: this
                    }
                });

                //Checkbox for toggling blocked items
                this.down('#checkbox').add({
                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                    id: 'blockedFilter',
                    fieldLabel: 'Find Blocked Items in Iteration?',
                    padding: '5,5,5,5',
                    margin: '-31px 0px 0px 225px',
                    handler: this._onChecked
                });
            },

            //Function that launches the grid
            _onLoad: function(comboBox) {
                Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                    type:'UserStory',
                    success:this._onModelRetrieved,
                    scope: this
                });
            },

            //Updates grid when iteration dropdown is changed
            _onChange: function() {
                var filterConfig = {
                    property:'Iteration',
                    operator: '=',
                    value: this.down('#iterationComboBox').getValue()
                };
                this.grid.filter(filterConfig, true, true);
            },

            //BEGIN: POINT OF INTEREST
            _getFilter: function() {
                var filter = [];
                if (Ext.getCmp('#blockedFilter').getValue()) this.grid.filter.push('Blocked');
                return filter;
            },

            _onChecked: function() {
                var changeBlock = this._getFilter();
                var config = {
                    types: changeBlock
                };
                this.grid.refresh(config);
            },
            //END: POINT OF INTEREST

            //Displays the main grid of information on the page
            _onModelRetrieved: function(model) {
                this.grid = this.down('#grid').add({
                    xtype:'rallygrid',
                    model: model,
                    id: 'iterationgrid',
                    pagingToolbarCfg:{
                        pageSizes: [25, 50, 100, 200]
                    },

                    columnCfgs:[
                        'FormattedID',
                        'Name',
                        'Iteration',
                        'Status',
                        'Blocked',
                        'Project'
                    ],

                    storeConfig:{
                        context: this.context.getDataContext(),
                        filters:[
                            {
                                property:'Iteration',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: this.down('#iterationComboBox').getValue()
                            },
                            {
                                property: 'Blocked',
                                operator: '=',
                                value: this.down('#blockedFilter').getValue()
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'User Stories By Iteration'
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Any information is helpful, as I am new to both Rally and Javascript. If there is a feature in Rally that does this already, I would like to know, but this app is actually for a feature I would like to implement with custom fields, I am just trying to get the architecture down first.

Answer (score 0):

2.0p4 is a pretty old preview version of App SDK 2.0.  If possible you should upgrade to use the 2.0 GA version, just released this week.

Check out this example in the docs: http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/filterable-grid

It uses a combobox to filter a grid.  Substituting a checkbox should be fairly straightforward.

Since it seems like you are always scoping by iteration you can also extend [Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp](http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp).  That will allow your app to work on an Iteration scoped custom page as well as simplify your code (it will create the iteration combobox for you if needed).

The example here shows how to do that part (although it is refreshing a board, but refreshing a grid should be the same as the filterable grid example above):

http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/timebox_filtering-section-timebox-required-apps